# Basic auth is not working for Traefik v2.1

Tags: basic-authentication, traefik

my issue is that I cannot set the [basic authentication](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/basicauth/#users) for my frontend app throught traefik

This is how I have configured my traefik

traefik.yml

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

entryPoints:
  https:
    address: :443
  http:
    address: :80
  traefik:
    address: :8080

tls:
  options:
    foo:
      minVersion: VersionTLS12
      cipherSuites:
        - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
        - "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

providers:
  providersThrottleDuration: 2s
  docker:
    watch: true
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: web

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

log:
  level: INFO

certificatesResolvers:
  default:
    acme:
      storage: /acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/srv/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml"
      - "/srv/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json"
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And here is where I have my frontend app running as a traefik provider and where I have my basic auth label

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    image: git.xxxx.com:7000/dockerregistry/registry/xxxx
    restart: "always"
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - "/srv/config/api.js:/var/www/htdocs/api.js"
      - "/srv/efs/workspace:/var/www/htdocs/stock"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.rule=Host(`test.xxxx.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.service=frontend
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=default
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`test.xxxx.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.service=frontend
      - traefik.http.middlewares.frontend.basicAuth.users=test:$$2y$$05$$c45HvbP0Sq9EzcfaXiGNsuuWMfPhyoFZVYgiTylpMMLtJY2nP1P6m
      - traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

I cannot get the login prompt, so Im wondering if I missing some container label for this.

Thanks in advance! Joaquin

Comment: Could you have found a solution cause am facing the same issue

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455229/traefik-basic-auth-does-not-work-with-https

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Docker Compose file **don't add the "middlewares" label** for `traefik`, instead do it using a `traefik.yml` file passing the `providers.file` option, where you should define the routers, services, middlewares, etc. In that "providers file" you should set `middlewares` under `http.routes.traefik` – This may sound super confuse at the beginning but is not that hard, trust me.

Let's do a YAML case (you can convert it to "TOML" [here](https://www.convertsimple.com/convert-yaml-to-toml/)).

This example assumes you have a Docker Compose file **specifically for Traefik** – I haven't tried using the same Docker Compose file with any other services in it (like Wordpress, databases or whatever) since I already have a different path for those files.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    [ ... ]
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Map the dynamic conf into the container
      - ./traefik/config.yml:/etc/traefik/config.yml:ro
      # Map the static conf into the container
      - ./traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro
      # Note you don't use "traefik.http.routers.<service>.middlewares etc." here
[ ... ]
```

In this case I set/get the config files for Traefik in `./traefik` (relative to the `docker-compose.yml` file).

`./traefik/config.yml`

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    traefik:
      middlewares: "basicauth"
      [ ... ]
  middlewares:
    basicauth:
      basicAuth:
        removeHeader: true
        users:
          - <user>:<password>
          # password should be generated using `htpasswd` (md5, sha1 or bcrypt)
[ ... ]
```

Here you can set the `basicauth` name as you wish (since that's the middleware name you'll see in the Dashboard), so you could do:

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    traefik:
      middlewares: "super-dashboard-auth"
      [ ... ]
  middlewares:
    super-dashboard-auth:
      basicAuth:
        removeHeader: true
        users:
          - <user>:<password>
          # password should be generated using `htpasswd` (md5, sha1 or bcrypt)
[ ... ]
```

Note that `basicAuth` must remain *as is*. Also, here you don't need to use the "double dollar method" to scape it (as in the [label approach](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.4/middlewares/basicauth/)), so after creating the user password you should enter it exactly like `htpasswd` created it.

```
# BAD
user:$$2y$$10$$nRLqyZT.64JI/CD/ym65UGDn8HaY0D6CBTxhe6JXf9u4wi5bEMdh.

# GOOD
user:$2y$10$nRLqyZT.64JI/CD/ym65UGDn8HaY0D6CBTxhe6JXf9u4wi5bEMdh.
```

Of course you may want to get this data from an `.env` file and not *hardcode* those strings, in that case you need to pass the environmental variable from the `docker-compose.yml` using `environment` like this:

```yaml
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: traefik
    [ ... ]
    environment:
      TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER: "${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER}"
      TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_PWD: "${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_PWD}"
      # And any other env. var. you may need
[ ... ]
```

and use it like this in you `traefik/config.yml` file:

```yaml
[ ... ]
middlewares:
    super-dashboard-auth:
      basicAuth:
        removeHeader: true
        users:
          - "{{env "TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_USER"}}:{{env "TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_PWD"}}"
[ ... ]
```

After that include the previous file in the `providers.file.filename`

`./traefik/traefik.yml`

```yaml
[ ... ]

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: false

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    [ ... ]

  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/config.yml
    watch: true

[ ... ]
```

And then simply `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: +1 for the #BAD and #GOOD basicAuth examples. I've spent days trying to figure out the basic authentication. Turns out that I was escaping the $ in my .htpasswd as if it was in docker label. For anyone coming here in the future, **do not escape the password in external files!** Thanks!

Comment: It was happening the same as @HannonQueiroz to me, I was reading the password from an env file, and I was also escaping it. Seems that every way of providing the password is superior to embedding it on labels!

Answer (score 11):

firstly , the labels should be in quotation marks like this ""

secondly, I think you are missing a label in the frontend app .
when using basic auth it takes two steps and should look like this :

```
  - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=frontend-auth"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend-auth.basicauth.users=test:$$2y$$05$$c45HvbP0Sq9EzcfaXiGNsuuWMfPhyoFZVYgiTylpMMLtJY2nP1P6m"
```

Answer (score 2):

I configure it this way:

1. generate password by *apache2-utils* e.g.

```
htpasswd -nb admin secure_password
```

2. setup traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
      to = "websecure"
      scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
  dashboard = true

[certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme]
  email = "your_email@your_domain"
  storage = "acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.tlsChallenge]

[providers.docker]
  watch = true
  network = "web"

[providers.file]
  filename = "traefik_dynamic.toml"
```

3. setup traefik_dynamic.toml

```
[http.middlewares.simpleAuth.basicAuth]
  users = [
    "admin:$apr1$ruca84Hq$mbjdMZBAG.KWn7vfN/SNK/"
  ]

[http.routers.api]
  rule = "Host(`monitor.your_domain`)"
  entrypoints = ["websecure"]
  middlewares = ["simpleAuth"]
  service = "api@internal"
  [http.routers.api.tls]
    certResolver = "lets-encrypt"
```

4. setup traefik service

```
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    restart: always
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./traefik_dynamic.toml:/traefik_dynamic.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
```

Comment: neither worked using a dynamic configuration like you. I maintained the format yml for traefik. could be that the bug?

Comment: What gets my attention is that in my configuration _simpleAuth_ is set in _http.routers.api_ section what i can't see in your yaml configuration. So maybe this middleware was not connected?

Comment: I suggest you also update traefik to 2.3 or higher version and try to use the example from the [documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/basicauth)

Comment: mm  stills without work. I implemented the dynamic file as you but is not working, the middleware is set. Intereseting that neither worked using the label in the docker service. 
https://gist.github.com/joaquindiazs/2689ae69ebd284062aee175e9dfdd139

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this [part of the documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.1/middlewares/overview/#provider-namespace).

If you are using Docker scripts for settings.
Configure as the following.
For example:

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.foo-add-prefix.addprefix.prefix=/foo"
      - "traefik.http.routers.router1.middlewares=foo-add-prefix@docker"
```

I had same issue and I was missing namespace name `@docker` in the middleware name.